# MessageSecurityException, UsernamePasswordValidator, and HttpWebRequest Problem

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

is there a better way to return back the standard "Invalid username/password" message to clients that connect to a WCF service requiring credentials? I have the following code, which causes an exception when I connect to my WCF service with invalid usernames/passwords.

Ideally I'd like back just a simple string, but to get the UsernamePasswordValidator to signal bad usernames requires throwing either a **FaultException** or **SecurityTokenException**, which causes an exception on the client-side at the HttpWebRequest's GetResponse method.

```
FileInfo file = new FileInfo("Request.xml");
string payload = file.OpenText().ReadToEnd();

HttpWebRequest request = HttpWebRequest.Create(URL) as HttpWebRequest;
request.ContentType = "text/xml";
request.ContentLength = payload.Length;
request.MediaType = "utf-8";
request.Method = "POST";
StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream());
writer.Write(payload);
writer.Flush();
writer.Close();

Console.WriteLine("Awaiting Response...");
HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
Console.WriteLine(reader.ReadToEnd());
Console.ReadKey(true);
```

The reason I want to do that is the service will be hit by clients not using .NET.

Comment: I believe a FaultException, when consumed by a non .NET client is provided as a standard SOAP Fault, so the client can expect this and handle it as needed. I think the FaultException is like a .NET wrapper for a SOAP fault for use in .NET clients and services? If this is true I'd recommend sticking with FaultException.

Comment: "Invalid username/password" isn't standard, as far as I know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put it in a `try - catch` statement and catch the exception, then pass your own message in the catch block